# How to destroy pre cookie value

Tags: asp.net

I have an issue to destroy pre cookie value in asp.net. Let me explain the problem description here.

We have two pages on our website. Lets say login.aspx and mainpage.aspx. My requirement is to change session id after login . For this case we have integrated following script in the login page before redirecting to main page something like this to change session id after login.

```
 protected void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        regenerateId();
        Response.Redirect("mainpage.aspx");
}




void regenerateId()
    {
        System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager manager = new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
        string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(Context);
        string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
        bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;
        manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newId, out isRedir, out isAdd);
        HttpApplication ctx = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
        HttpModuleCollection mods = ctx.Modules;
        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule ssm = (SessionStateModule)mods.Get("Session");
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = ssm.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = null;
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo rqIdField = null, rqLockIdField = null, rqStateNotFoundField = null;
        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Name.Equals("_store")) store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)field.GetValue(ssm);
            if (field.Name.Equals("_rqId")) rqIdField = field;
            if (field.Name.Equals("_rqLockId")) rqLockIdField = field;
            if (field.Name.Equals("_rqSessionStateNotFound")) rqStateNotFoundField = field;
        }
        object lockId = rqLockIdField.GetValue(ssm);
        if ((lockId != null) && (oldId != null)) store.ReleaseItemExclusive(Context, oldId, lockId);
        rqStateNotFoundField.SetValue(ssm, true);
        rqIdField.SetValue(ssm, newId);

        
    }
```

After redirecting to main page we can able to see session id got changed. This is fine up to here.

But still able to access the old session details. If we type old session id still able to see the all internal information in the main page. So how to destroy the pre cookie value after login . Can you please explain how to handle this case.

Comment: Why are you using WebForms?

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-cookie"?

Comment: The "script" you've integrated is utterly horrible. You should not be using reflection for this.